# Use while loop with continue statement to print all letters except 'p' and 'r'. a = 'happyfriday'

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am learning how to use while loop for the continue statement and trying to print all letters except 'p' and 'r' in a string: a = 'happyfriday'

I tried several ways but unable to figure out, my current version is:

```
a= 'happyfriday'
while True:
    if a == "g":
        continue
    if a =="o":
        continue
print(a)
```

Comment: If you want to skip `p` and `r` how could having if statements comparing to `g` and `o` possibly help you? Also, the print statement needs to be *inside* the while loop. You also should loop over the letters in a, like `for letter in a:`

Comment: You've assigned the string `'happyfriday'` to `a`, so `a` will never be `"g"` or `"o"`. Since you say you want to use `while` for the loop, you probably want some variable to index `a` (say `i`) and increase it on every iteration to access characters in `a` with `a[i]`.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. I can't understand your thought process. In your own words, where the code says `if a == "g":`, what do you think this means? How does this help to solve the problem? Also: why do you want to use a `while` loop to solve the problem?

Comment: This happens. He is new to coding. Keep it up @sal. You'll get the hang of it! For now follow the comments and change the 'g' and 'o'

Answer (score 0):

Try this, what you need to loop through is string a

```
a = 'happyfriday'
index = 0
while index < len(a):
    if (value := a[index]) in ("p", "r"):
        index += 1
        continue
    else:
        print(value)
        index += 1
```